# Laravel - Sass variables

Tags: laravel, sass, tabulator

I'm coming to you because I would like to use the [Tabulator http://tabulator.info/](http://tabulator.info/) library in a Laravel project. I have correctly installed the library in my project (import of css and js scripts).
**Terminal** :

```
npm install tabulator-tables
```

**resources/js/app.js**:

```js
window.Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.js');
```

**resources/js/app.scss**:

```
@import 'variables';
@import "../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css";
@import "../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap.min.css";
```

And to stylize the tables a bit, Tabulator provides a system to use sass variables.

**resources/js/_variables.scss**:

```
$backgroundColor:black;
$headerBackgroundColor: #3F3F3F;
$headerTextColor: #fff;
$borderColor:#FFE6;
$rowTextColor: #000000;
$rowSelectedBackground: #FFE6A8;
@import "../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator_simple.min.css";
```

But as indicated in the [documentation http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/style#sass](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/style#sass), it is enough to override the variables used by the library to style the tables. But when I do `npm run dev`, no changes are made. Would you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i have noticed that i import the wrong file in `resources/scss/app.scss`.

```
//wrong way
@import "../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css";
//good way
@import "../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/src/scss/tabulator_simple";
```